# Opportunity - letter "t" may be added in the Amount field

Tags: fields

The letter "t" may be added in the amount field on Opportunity creation. It then adds zeroes to the amount, equal to the number after it, so for example if the user inputs 2t in the amount field, then it will be updated to 2,000,000,000,000.00.

[image]

Please confirm why amount field is accepting "t" letter.

Comment: That is not achievable by standard thing, you might need to create custom page/component for this, which will update the field value.

Comment: @rahul : for standard field only i am getting updation, please help me why amount field allowing letters as well and updating amount as well.

Comment: Not sure, but my org is giving an error on entering '2t'

Comment: Check if edit/new buttons are overridden